# MongoDB uniqueness of a field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my application each user can only have one active conversation.

```json
{
  _id: ...,
  user: 1,
  active: true
},
{
  _id: ...,
  user: 1,
  active: false
},
  _id: ...,
  user: 1,
  active: false
}
```

**Index**

```js
ConversationSchema.index({ user: 1, active: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

How to ignore `false` values and just check uniqueness for `true` values for a specific user.

Comment: That is just not how unique index is intended for. You should handle this with your application code

Answer (score 0):

```
For compound indexes(ESR), this rule of thumb is helpful in deciding the order of fields in the index NOT TO IGNORE THE VALUES YOU ASKED:

>First, add those fields against which Equality queries are run.
>The next fields to be indexed should reflect the Sort order of the query.
>The last fields represent the Range of data to be accessed.

So by following that and querying the executionStats.

    "indexBounds": {
      "createdAt": [
       "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
      ]
     }
the above snippet in the execution stats will tell you the Max & Min which is to choose the index.

And rest as @Ray mentioned you above, handle the ignored ones from the code.
```